# Dynamically adding image AND src from xml

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm using xml to populate a html site (so the flash site can be ported automatically for those without flash).

```
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {                   
        //    VARS   //
        //Set up Vars for <li> elements
        var src = x[i].getElementsByTagName("image")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        //    IMG   //
        //If 'name' node is present, append 'name' to #filmsfuturereleases
        if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("image")[0].childNodes.length) {
            document.write('<img src="', src, '"/>');
        } else {
            document.write("&nbsp;")
        }
    }
```

In the code I set the 'src' variable and then use a loop to write each image.

I'd like to get rid of the document.write functions and replace with something like append, so I could put the image into a list.

I can do this when I'm using text (append text var to an li element), but since I'm dynamically adding the image AND the image src, I'm having trouble.

Any ideas? jQuery can be used, xslt cannot...

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like that

```
$img = $('<img />').attr('src', $(x[i]).find('image').text());
$('#filmsfuturereleases').append($img);
```

Comment: Setting the img to a var suits me perfectly, thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you know how I could avoid using _document.write("&nbsp;")_ so the loop doesn't break?

Comment: the same manner, use `$(element-to-append-to).append(element-to-append)`

Comment: basically you should avoid using document.write in general

Comment: Thanks, I meant what could I put to pass a null value rather than using the &nbsp; to continue the loop (the loop breaks if I try and pass a null value)?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, if you do not want to append space (`&nbsp;`) just remove whole else branch, cycle will be broken if you manually break it or exception is thrown

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use jQuery and you can put images inside a div, here's the code

```
$('#filmsfuturereleases').append($('<img src="', src, '"/>'));
```

If you pass a HTML snippet to jQuery function it creates the DOM element for it.

OR

```
$('#filmsfuturereleases').append('<img src="', src, '"/>');
```

Comment: I decided not to go with this one, but I'm using the method to simplify another part of my script, so thanks!